# Sublime text folder tree/sidebar and SSHFS mounted files

Tags: sublimetext2, directory, remote-server, sublimetext3, sshfs

I have mounted a large project over SSHFS, but notice ST3's folder sidebar will not expand the folder tree when I go to open to root directory (one with many subfolders/files). It appears as if the folder is empty.

If I open a smaller subfolder it performs as usual, but this makes it very difficult to work with.

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Sometimes you have to refresh the tree, and other times `umount` and try to mount again.  ST stumbles with large trees at times.

Comment: I've tried umount and restarting ST/re-adding the folder. Is there a way to refresh the tree I don't know of? (not much experience with ST)

Comment: I am not sure out of the box, but [SideBarEnhancements](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements/tree/st3) has a refresh option when you right-click an item in the tree.

Comment: Thanks, funnily enough I had found and tried this before your reply - no luck!

Answer (score 0):

refresh the folder tree with Project -> Refresh Folders